# Each button plays and pauses a song, but previous song won't terminate when another is selected

Tags: reactjs

[image: Audio Selections]

So far, I have successfully created an audio player that will play a selected song on button click, pausing and resuming the audio along the way. The problem occurs when I click a button to make another selection *while* a selection is currently playing. I am wanting to kill the previous song so the new selection will be loaded and ready to play when the play button is clicked again.

My focus has been working *audioRef.current=null* into my *handleCurrentItem()* function, but all attempts at that has been a bust. Would someone direct me on a proper approach to this problem?
My working code follows.

```
import over from "./over.wav";
import pretty from "./pretty1.mp3";
import diary from "./diary.mp3";

const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    musicSrc: over,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    musicSrc: pretty,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    musicSrc: diary,
  },
];

const App = () => {
  const [currentItem, setCurrentItem] = useState(2);
  return (
    <div className="audio-container">
      <BtnSet
        data={data}
        currentItem={currentItem}
        setCurrentItem={setCurrentItem}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

const BtnSet = ({ data, currentItem, setCurrentItem }) => {
  function handleCurrentItem(index) {
    setCurrentItem(index);
  }
  return (
    <>
      {data.map((audioItem, index) => {
        return (
          <>
            <button key={audioItem.id} onClick={() => handleCurrentItem(index)}>
              Audio {index + 1}
            </button>
          </>
        );
      })}
      <AudioFunctionality data={data} currentItem={currentItem} />
    </>
  );
};

const AudioFunctionality = ({ data, currentItem }) => {
  const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(false);
  let audioRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    audioRef.current = new Audio(data[currentItem].musicSrc);
  }, [currentItem, data]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isPlaying) {
      audioRef.current.play().catch((err) => {
        console.log("Failed to start playback ", err);
      });
    } else {
      audioRef.current.pause();
    }
  }, [isPlaying]);

  return (
    <AudioControls isPlaying={isPlaying} onPlayPauseClick={setIsPlaying} />
  );
};

const AudioControls = ({ isPlaying, onPlayPauseClick }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {isPlaying ? (
        <button
          type="button"
          className="play-pause-btn"
          onClick={() => onPlayPauseClick(false)}
          aria-label="Pause"
        >
          <TbPlayerPause className="play-btn" />
        </button>
      ) : (
        <p
          type="button"
          className="play-pause-btn"
          onClick={() => onPlayPauseClick(true)}
          aria-label="Play"
        >
          <TbPlayerPlay />
        </p>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your current implementation is that when the `AudioFunctionality` component renders again with a new `currentItem`, a new Audio object is created without stopping the previous one, which continues playing.

What you need to do is to stop the current track before a new Audio object is made. One way to do this would be to add a cleanup function to the `useEffect` that creates the Audio object, like so:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (audioRef.current) {
    audioRef.current.pause();
    audioRef.current.currentTime = 0;
  }
  audioRef.current = new Audio(data[currentItem].musicSrc);
  return () => {
    if (audioRef.current) {
      audioRef.current.pause();
      audioRef.current.currentTime = 0;
    }
  }
}, [currentItem, data]);
```

Comment: Nice!! Thanks for the education Kobra.

Comment: Happy to help, friend! :D